# git перестал запрашивать пароль

Tags: git, gitlab, git-bash

После того как я не правильно ввел пароль в гите он перестал его спрашивать и при запросе вечно выдает ошибку типа:

```
$ git push --set-upstream origin master
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for ...
```

Как мне вернуть возможность вводить пароль?

У меня возникло подозрение что windows заблокировал доступ. Возможно у кого то било уже такое?

Comment: Я бы скопировал изменённые файлы в другое место, удалил всю папку с клона репозитория и склонировал текущую ветку. Потом файлы на место и коммитить.

Comment: @Adokenai Не помогло

Comment: а на сам Гит пропускает? Может IP забанили (что странно)

Comment: Скорее всего git закэшировал ваш неверный пароль в своих настройках, запросите `git config -l` и увидите что он там сохранил

Comment: @Barmaley А что искать то?

Comment: @Adokenai не на сайт спокойно заходит

Comment: Ищите секцию `[credential]` - если есть удалите ее

Comment: @Barmaley А как удалить секцию [credential] ?

Comment: @МиколаМірчук `git config --remove-section credential`

Comment: Отредактируйте вручную файл: `~/.gitconfig` - скорее всего это он, но возможен вариант `etc/gitconfig` или `.git/config` - в общем держитесь :)

Comment: @Arhad а вот теперь реально странно команда 
    
git config --remove-section credential
видала ошибку 
fatal: no such section: credential
хотя в списке конфигов бил
credential.helper=manager

Comment: @Barmaley А чем редактировать? Тот же стандартный блокнот не принимает юниксовые переводы строки, по остальным же редакторам надо проверять и подбирать нужный (но это, как по мне, чистое издевательство над вопрошающим). Так что через командную строку (как я указал выше) надёжнее, да и случайно удалить лишнее становится значительно сложнее.

Comment: Ну если вы сидите под *nix'ом надо уметь хотя бы пользоваться `vi`, ну или хотя бы `emacs` - это не издевательство, так сказать требования оси :)

Comment: `git` держит свой конфиг в нескольких местах... - читайте матчасть `git config --help` вам в помощь

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15381198/4827341 , ну и https://stackoverflow.com/q/47860772/4827341